# Componente - UI para hierarquia

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2, vuetify

Estou precisando montar uma exibição tipo `treeview`(mas não me apego ao design treeview) para exibir uma estrutura de forma hierárquica.

Não achei nada relacionado a isso no *vuetify*.

Comment: Especifique um pouco melhor o que você quer (uma imagem talvez?). Você já viu isso [Vue.D3.tree](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.D3.tree)

Comment: eu consegui achar o ivew, eu objetivo seria uma espécie de treeview. Agora estou na tentativa de implementar um nodeKey personalizado